# Laravel 8 getting BindingResolutionException error after upgrade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

After upgrading `Laravel v:7` to `8` i get below error and i can't resolve that

```
Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
Target class [Frontend\HomeController] does not exist.
```

my controller `namespace` and directory structure:

```
|- app
    |- Http
        |- Controllers
            |- Frontend
                 -HomeController.php
             - Controller.php
```

Route:

```php
Route::namespace('Frontend')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
});
```

and then `HomeController.php`

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Frontend;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        dd('aaaa');
    }

    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

using below command could't resolve my problem too:

```sh
php artisan clear-compiled
php artisan optimize:clear
composer dump-autoload
```

Answer (score 4):

In laravel 8, you need to do it like this:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Frontend\HomeController;

Route::get('/', [HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
```

No automatic namespace prefixing will be done by Laravel in V8.

Comment: Automatic namespace prefixing is still *theoretically* possible but it is actively discouraged and is no longer in the default boilerplates.

Comment: There are the Docs for Laravel 8.x: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#basic-controllers